# Fragment call cause application not responding

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

i'm a bit stuck in this task. I have an app which displays a main fragment embedding google maps,  now i would like to replace it with another fragment showing some charts when the user clicks a send button inside a drawer menu list.

When i click send application get stuck, giving me the hated "Application Not Responding". However, if i change the android:name field into the same of the maps fragment, it works and display the map correctly.

Main activity snippet where i launch maps fragment

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    mapsFragment = new MapsFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.maincontainer,mapsFragment)
            .commit();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

Main Activity snippet where i launch the charts fragment

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        Snackbar snackbar;
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_manage:
                snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, "manage", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:
                snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, "share", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_send:
                snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, "send", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
                fragment = new ChartsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_view:
                snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, "view", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
                break;
        }
        if(fragment != null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.maincontainer,fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
        item.setChecked(true);
        // Set action bar title
        //setTitle(item.getTitle());
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)
findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

MapsFragment onCreate

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mContext = getActivity();
        return rootView;
    }
```

ChartsFragment onCreate

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_charts, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Main appbar xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout_app_bar_main"
    tools:context="com.fabio.gis.geotag.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_activity" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/place_marker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/secondaryColorAccent"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_marker" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/send_positions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_24dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Maps fragment

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_ui"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>
</RelativeLayout>

Charts Fragment

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/charts_ui"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/charts"
         android:name="com.fabio.gis.geotag.ChartsFragment"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello World!" />

     </fragment>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I already tried to replace

> android:name="com.fabio.gis.geotag.ChartsFragment"

with

> class="com.fabio.gis.geotag.ChartsFragment"

Nothing changed.

Thanks in advance for your support. I realize i'm a beginner in android, maybe i'm struggling for just a stupid rookie mistake.

After a while it remain in ANR it gave me the following stacktrace error

```
03-06 17:11:43.322 7033-7033/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                 at com.fabio.gis.geotag.ChartsFragment.onCreateView(ChartsFragment.java:20)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1370)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                 at com.fabio.gis.geotag.ChartsFragment.onCreateView(ChartsFragment.java:20)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1370)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                 at com.fabio.gis.geotag.ChartsFragment.onCreateView(ChartsFragment.java:20)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1370)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)

                                             read: unexpected EOF!
```

Comment: can you please post the error log

Comment: i posted the stacktrace it gave me after a while the app was in ANR, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may concern, the error was caused by some inconsistent library references versions in gradle file, causing possible unexpected runtime exceptions.

The problem has been tackled in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Hope it can save hours to someone in future.